# Serving Angular2 app at a base URL with Express

Tags: node.js, angular, web-services, express

I have an Angular2 app up and running and a very simple express server. Is it possible to only serve my application when a user visits '/app' (for example)? 
If yes how can it be implemented?

I intend to have multiple Angular apps on different URLs and all of these need scripts. Hence a solution which takes care of which script to handle when would be desired.

---

Edit- Along with the accepted answer, if using the angular-cli, the 'base-href' has to be set to the URL of the app when building the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.

You have to define that endpoint as the only one:

```
app.get('/app', function (req, res) {
  res.send(/* your application */)
})
```

Comment: Yes of course, but I have the built Angular2 application in the /app folder and whenever index.html loads it also tries to load other files which the Angular app depends on. I need to have multiple Angular apps running on multiple URLs and I need a way to serve these dependencies according to each app

Comment: All of the resources are provided through the express framework. The resources referenced by the index.html are usually part of the static files that are served, e.g. through something like: `app.use('/resourcesForApp', express.static('folderWithResourcesForAppOnServer'))`

Comment: However, when the application looks for scripts by asking for a `src`, for example, `inline.bundle.js`, it gets interpreted as `domain.com/inline.bundle.js` instead of `domain.com/app/inline.bundle.js`

Comment: What do you mean by "the application"? You definitely need to provide some code and more information on your setup (e.g. bundler)...

Comment: Sorry for all the confusion. I have found the solution. Along with doing what you had mentioned, the 'base-href' argument also needs to be provided. Thanks +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
// serve the angular web page
app.get('/', app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname+'/../../public'))));
```

**Note**: change the dir name to reach your directory where contains the angular static files.